# Let T: P2-> P2 linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: P2 \rightarrow P2$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(p) = p''(x) + 2p(x).$

$a)$ Find the matrix $A$ of the linear transformation $T$.

Comment: What is $P2$? Do you mean the set of polynomials of degree at most 2?

Comment: ya I guess. I'm not that great at math. should have vectors (X^2,x,1) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The columns of a matrix are the images of the basis vectors (in the chosen basis of the range/codomain). For example, the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&2 \\ 3&4 \end{array}\right)$ sends the basis vector $(1,0)$ to $(1,3)$ and sends $(0,1)$ to $(2,4)$.

In your example, the space is $3$-dimensional, so it will be a 3-by-3 matrix. Your basis is $\{1,x,x^2\}$. Think of $1$ as $(1,0,0)$, $x$ as $(0,1,0)$ and $x^2$ as $(0,0,1)$. Write what your linear map does to these three things, and express the answers again as linear combinations of $1,x,$ and $x^2$, and the coefficients will be the columns. For instance, $T(1) = 2$, so the first column of the matrix is $\left(\begin{array}{c} 2\\0\\0 \end{array}\right)$. Next, $T(x) = 2x$, so the second column is $\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$.

Hopefully you can figure out the third column on your own from this.

Comment: kinda but not really.

Comment: Let T : P^2 -> P^2 be the linear transformation defined by T(p) = p''(x) + 2p(x).

(a) Find the matrix A of the linear transformation T.

(b) Use A to find the image of p(x) = 2x^2 + 3x + 4. Use linearity to compute
T(-3p).

(c) Use A to find all q ∈ P2 such that T(q) = 0. Use linearity to compute T(p+q), where p is given in question 3b. Is T 1-to-1? Explain.

Comment: that's much pretty much the whole question. not sure why it gets clumped up like that.

Comment: $T(x^2) = 2 + 2x^2$, so the third column is $\left( \begin{array}{c} 2\\0\\2 \end{array} \right)$. Does this make sense why that is true?

Comment: Ya starting to get it now. You just put in {1.x,x^2} into the equations.
T(1)=(1)''+2(1) and do the derivities to get T(1)=2

Comment: Right, and think of "2" as $2 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2$, the corresponding linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: okay. So I got a matrix A = T(x^2) | T(x) | T(1) = (202) | (020) | (002). Sorry, don't know how to do the cool way you do it.

Comment: For part b) I'm representing p(x) = 2(x^2) +3x+4 as column (234). Since T(-3p), do I just multiply A*-3(234)?

Comment: Yes, or just $-3 \cdot A \left(\begin{array}{c}2\\3\\4\end{array}\right)$ (since $T$ is linear).

Comment: for part c, I went with T(p+q) = T(p) + T(q). Since T(q) = 0, I'm just left with T(p). T(p)=A(p) and just did RREF of A | p. that's about all I got, trying to figure out if it is 1-to-1

Comment: To see if it's 1 to 1, compute the determinant. If it's non-zero, then it's 1-to-1. If it's zero, then it's NOT 1-to-1.